# How incorrect would it be to say "Il lance la balle à moi"?

Tags: grammaire

Is the sentence "Il lance la balle à moi" completely incorrect, or is it merely just awkward and heavy? Or, is it in fact sometimes acceptable in certain contexts (for example, to emphasize that it's *me* who he throws it to, instead of his best friend)?

Comment: Very bad, in my opinion. BUT: Il **m'a lancé la balle,  à moi, pas à toi**. Only in speech.

Comment: You know when I was learning French, during my teenage years, I just took what was given to me. If you just go along in stages without over analyzing, you will *come to hear* these things for yourself. Well, that's my two cents. However, one has to first internalize a whole bunch of stuff....

Comment: If I undestand you correctly, you think I would be better to not think of these questions that are "overanalysing", because I will learn what is correct or not through years of exposure. I, on the other hand, believe that there is use to such "overanalysis", and I wish that it would be assumed that it is valid and useful for me to ask such questions without me having to justify them. Justification for this question is: It is common for beginners to translate the English "He threw the ball at me" into the word-for-word "Il lancé la balle à moi", and I wanted to know how incorrect that was.

Comment: I don't know what beginners do or don't do. How could I possibly know that? Every beginner is different. I learned French at first through systematic lessons in books.  One of my books had all the idiomatic expressions in every text at the end, in a list. I am not saying don't ask questions, I am saying that if you see a grammar rule, don't try and change the rule right off the bat. First, let it sink in. Anyway, I answered your actual question, didn't I? :)

Comment: Hi silph, I'd suggest you read the sections on object pronouns and stressed pronouns in *French Grammar and Usage* by Hawkins and Towell. It's probably at the right level for you (judging by some of your questions), and it's good at comparing French and English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be marginally correct in some  contexts, rather rare, as for example in a stream of consciousness strain of thinking.

- Il lance la balle à  moi… m'y attendais pas… ma veine… encore raté… (*understated: "not to someone slse"*)

The case proposed by **user Lambie** in the comments  (modification) is also correct, if slightly changed (you can't use the object pronoun "*me*" as it makes for redundancy with "*à moi*".

- Il a lancé la balle à moi, pas à toi.

However, with the introduction of a second comma and stressing of "à moi", as written in her comment, it is also correct.

- Il m'a lancé la balle, à moi, pas à toi.

There is no redundancy here as "à moi" is used to insist on the fact.

Comment: and if i understand you correctly, in most (all) other situations, it would sound completely incorrect?

Comment: @silph That is what I believe to be true, but it is not impossible that some other cases might exist that have escaped my observation.

Comment: J'ai bien écrit:  **Il m'a lancé la balle, à moi**, pas à toi. C'est tout.

Comment: LPH, i just want you to know that i found your entire answer completely understandable, even if Lambie thinks the English is too non-standard. i appreciate you writing up the answer and responding to my question for clarification.

Comment: @Lambie Vous avez bien écrit "Il m'a lancé la balle, à moi, pas à toi.", oui, mais ce n'est pas la phrase dans la requête, puisque vous ajoutez une virgule après "balle"; il faut donc rendre cela bien clair, tout au moins aussi clair que possible. Je ne vois pas ce qu'il y a de bizarre à appeler une phrase un cas.

Comment: @Lambie Surveillez un peu vos participes passés, ils sont terminés en -er la moitié du temps… ça n'est pas à votre avantage, je vous l'assure…

Comment: [...]"ce n'est pas la phrase de la requête"? La requête pose la question: Is Il lance la balle à moi completely incorrect? Answer: Yes, it is. Il me lance la balle. OU Il me lance la balle, à moi. [emphatic] OU Il me lance la balle, à moi, pas à toi. [[emphatic not to you]. Et moi, je l'ai mis au passé composé dans ma réponse. Pourquoi est-ce que tu ne réponds pas clairement aux questions avant de te lancer à la mer?

Comment: @Lambie Vous ajoutez « m' » ; je l'enlève parce que j'estime que c'est redondant ; remarquez que je n'utilise pas la virgule (alors que vous mettez une virgule), et la phrase du PO n'a pas de virgule. Ce n'est pas la même chose : sans virgule il n'y a pas nécessairement de notion d'intensification (optionnelle) et « à moi » n'est pas nécessairement emphatique.

Answer (score 4):

An addition to LPH's answer.

The sentence ***il donne la balle à moi*** is 100% understandable by native French speakers but the chance for it to be produced by them is close to 0%.

However here are some rare situations in which this construction might be heard.

1. You start a sentence without knowing who the ball will be given to then realize it's you:

> – *Il donne la balle... à moi !*

2. To preserve the word ordering of a previous sentence:

> – *La balle, il la donne à qui ?*
> – *Il la donne à moi !* (vs *il me la donne*)

3. When *à moi* has a complement:

> *Il donne la balle à moi et à personne d'autre.*
> *N'oublie pas, et lorsque tu pourras parler, **raconte-le, à moi** qui ai tout oublié*, Bernard Werber, *Nous, le dieux*, 2004

4. To emphazise "to me":

> *Il sursaute légèrement mais je sens son visage sourire sous mes doigts. "Je donne ma langue au chat." Je le bouscule gentiment. "**Donne-la à moi** plutôt."* https://degradation.skyrock.com/55.html

This kind of grammar can also be used to represent French spoken by non native people:

> *– Et c'est toi qui t'es chargé de l'exécution ?
>
> – Sa Hautesse **a donné l'ordre à moi**, dit le nègre en se redressant avec orgueil.
>
> – Mais c'est la besogne du bourreau et non la tienne.
>
> – Sa Hautesse pas avoir eu le temps d'emmener son bourreau, et **il a pris cuisiner à lui**. **Donnez donc à moi** un grand couteau pour couper la tête à Osmin.
>
> – C'est bien, c'est bien, interrompit le chef, on va te le chercher, ton grand couteau. Attends-moi ici.*

*Le Corricolo*, Alexandre Dumas, 1843.

> *– Mais il n'est au camp que quelques jours par mois.
>
> – Alors, qu'il donne l'argent pour nourrir et habiller ma fille.
>
> – Je connais Aïcha, Abd-El-Salam, elle n'acceptera jamais de l'argent.
>
> – Alors, **qu'il donne l'argent à moi**.*

*Les nouveaux seigneurs*, Pierre-Jean Maintigneux, 1961

Answer (score -2):

La balle il me l'a lancée à moi

Comment: Peux-tu développer ?

Comment: Pour faire voir que c'est à moi qu'il a lancé la balle

Comment: ça n'est pas une réponse à la question